# Show that the antiderivative $F$ satisfies $F(y)=F(z)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, curves, parametrization, line-integrals

> Let be $h:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function,
>
> $f:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ a vector field where $f(x):=h(x)x$,
>
> $C$ a continuously differentiable curve with $C\subset\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \Vert x\Vert_2=R\}$, where $R>0$ and $\int_C f(x)\cdot dx = 0.$
>
> Show that if $f$ has an antiderivative $F$, then for all $y,z\in\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$ with $\Vert y\Vert_2=\Vert z \Vert_2$ it holds
>
> $F(y)=F(z)$ and $h(y)=h(z)$.

**My approach:**

My idea so far was to find a continuously differentiable parametrization $\varphi:[\alpha,\beta]\to\mathbb{R}^n$ of a curve $C$ that connects two points $y$ and $z$. We assume $\Vert y\Vert_2=\Vert z\Vert_2=R>0$ and define
$$
\varphi[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^n, \text{ where } \varphi(t)=\frac{R}{\Vert\left(y+t(z-y)\right)\Vert_2}\left(y+t(z-y)\right).
$$
So for all $t\in[\alpha,\beta]$ we have $\Vert \varphi(t)\Vert_2=R$ and by the given assumption this means that $\int_C f(x)\cdot dx = 0$. As $F$ is an antiderivative we can conclude
$$
0=\int_C f(x)\cdot dx = F(y)-F(z)\implies F(y)=F(z).
$$
However, it could be that $y+t(z-y)=0$. Maybe there is another "easy" parametrization that excludes this case? Or is this approach useless? Do you have any hints for the part $h(y)=h(z)$?

**EDIT:**

I made some progress regarding the part $h(y)=h(z)$:

We assume that we can find a curve $C$ with a continuously differentiable parametrization $\varphi:[\alpha,\beta]\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ with $\varphi(\alpha)=y$ and $\varphi(\beta)=z$ such that $\varphi([\alpha,\beta])\subset \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid \Vert x\Vert_2=R\}$.

Then, $\int_C f(x)\cdot dx = F(y)-F(z)=0$ because $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$. So $h(y)y=h(z)z$.

If $h(z)=0$ then $h(y)=0$ because $y\neq0$. If $h(z)\neq0$ then $z=\frac{h(y)}{h(z)}y$ and from $\Vert y\Vert_2=\Vert z \Vert_2$ it follows immediately $h(y)=h(z)$.

Comment: One thing you could use to change your approach, if you want to, is that since y and z are only real numbers, you can have either y=z or y=-z from the conditions placed upon them. That means that you've proven that F(z)=F(y) and h(z)=h(y) when z=y, and leaves you with showing that F(y)=F(-y) and h(y)=h(-y)

Comment: @nxe, $y,z$ are not real numbers. They are vectors. what about $y=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,\cdots,0)$ and $z=(1,0,\cdots,0)$?

Comment: My mistake. The line you declare them on says they're both in ℝ, but their use in h would suggest otherwise

Comment: @nxe, there was a typo in my question that caused the misunderstanding. I've corrected it.